# Proving instability of non linear system given linear system is unstable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, nonlinear-system

I am self studying Control Theory from a book and in it the author asks a question --

If the linear system of ordinary differential equation is unstable ( at x=0 ) prove that  non linear system  is also unstable. ( Use linearization in non linear system ie if system is $X' = AX + g(X)$ , then you can assume that $||g(X) ||<k ||X||$ for suitable $||X||< k$ and  also assume that $A$ is a constant matrix) .

Can somebody please tell how to prove it.

Comment: Your question seems incomplete.  What about $\Vert g(x) \Vert$?  assume what exactly?

Comment: @ Robert Lewis I have edited it. Can you please help now.

Comment: I'm working on it but am very busy today so please be patient.  Thanks.

Comment: What you need is Theorem 4.7 in Khalil's book (in the chapter on linearization of nonlinear systems). This book is the most common textbook on nonlinear control systems.

Comment: @Arastas Are you taking about integral calculus and differential equations written by Khalil Ahmed?

Comment: No, about this one: https://www.egr.msu.edu/~khalil/NonlinearSystems/

Comment: @Arastas  thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Not true as stated.  Consider the nonlinear system

$$ \eqalign{x' = y - x^3\cr
            y' = - y^3\cr} $$
whose equilibrium at $(0,0)$ is asymptotically stable, although the linearized system
$$ \eqalign{ x' = y\cr 
             y' = 0\cr}$$ 
is unstable.

Comment: @ Robert Israel can you please suggest a book on topic stability of non linear system using linearization which contains theorems

Comment: You might try Lefschetz, [Differential Equations: Geometric Theory](https://books.google.ca/books?id=IjXvAAAAMAAJ)

Comment: @ Robert Israel if a linear system is unstable then it must have all characteristic roots with positive real part?

Comment: No, it has at least one with nonnegative real part (as in the example).