# On giving counterexamples in stability of non linear control systems

Tags: examples-counterexamples, control-theory, nonlinear-system

I am self studying control theory and I have a doubt. Can someone please help.

Question is -  Find examples to show that even if a linear system is stable then also corresponding non linear system may or may not be stable.

So, I need to construct two counterexamples 1. In which non linear system is unstable. 
2. Another in which non linear system is stable.

Can somebody please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if the linearized system at an equilibrium is stable, then the nonlinear system is at least locally stable around that equilibrium. Two examples for your cases with that in mind:

**First case**: Linearization stable, Nonlinear system globally stable:

$$
\dot{x} = -x -x^3 \tag{1}
$$

Lyapunov function $V(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2$ is $\dot{V}(x) = -x^4 - x^2 < 0$ for $x \neq 0$. Nonlinear system $(1)$ is globally stable. Linearization at $0$ is $\dot{x} = -x$, eigenvalue at $-1$, stable.

**Second case**: Linearization stable, Nonlinear system globally unstable (only localy stable):

$$
\dot{x} = -x + x^3 \tag{2}
$$

With initial condition $x(0) = 2$ the solution of $(2)$ is $x(t) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1 - \exp(2 t + \log(3/4))}}$, which has finite escape time so $(2)$ is unstable for some initial conditions. Linearization at $0$ is again $\dot{x} = -x$, which is stable. Also, $(2)$ cannot be globally stable because it has three equilibrium points: $0, 1$ and $-1$.

Comment: @ Sample Time thanks a lot

Comment: @ Sample time what does finite escape time means

Comment: @user686624 It means that the system diverges to infinity in finite time. Unstable linear systems for example have always infinite escape time, i.e. they "reach" infinity only in infinite time. Unstable nonlinear systems (like the one here) can have finite escape time, which is usually even worse than "normal" instability.

Comment: @ Sample time can you please look at this question also if you have some spare time.It is also asked by me. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411281/proving-instability-of-non-linear-system-given-linear-system-is-unstable

Comment: @ Sample time. I mean about solution of that question.  That result is given in my textbook as theoram to be proved.  Can you please tell how to prove it.

Comment: @user686624 Unfortunatly, I can't help with this question...

Comment: @ Sample time it is absolutely fine. You have already helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try systems where the linearized system is a "centre", e.g.

$$ \eqalign{x' &= y \cr
            y' &= -x \cr} $$
and add nonlinear terms to make $x^2+y^2$ increase or decrease.

Comment: can you please tell a book in which detailed treatment of non linear systems is given

Comment: @James https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/JtZFAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0

Comment: @avs Are you aware that James asked that question over 2 years ago?  I hope he found a book already.